# Python Min function using key: return minimum and its value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the minimum of a set using a specific ordering key. However I don't want to get just the minimum but also its value according to the used key.

Explaining this with a toy example:

The set `{"0", "00", "000"}` using `min({"0", "00", "000"}, key = len)` provides that the minimum is `"0"`. But I want the answer to be something like `("0",1)`.

What I am currently doing (explained in terms of the previous example) is:

```
my_set = {"0", "00", "000"}
minimum = min(my_set, key = len)
minimum_value = len(minimum)
result = (minimum, minimum_value)
```

However in the real application the key function is very expensive to evaluate so I would like to avoid running it this last extra time.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

So, you could do something like:

```
min(map(lambda x: (len(x), x), my_set))
```

Depending on the nature of `my_set`, this could be slightly different (since it is using the value in its comparison operation when `len(x)` are equal). To get the exactly equivalent behavior, you would need:

```
min(map(lambda x: (len(x), x), my_set), key=lambda t: t[0])
```

but this may not be necessary.

Also, you can use a generator expression instead of `map`, which is slightly more aesthetically pleasing to my eye:

```
min((len(x), x) for x in my_set)
min(((len(x), x) for x in my_set), key=lambda t: t[0])
```

Comment: Did you mean: `n = min(map(lambda x: (x, len(x)), s), key=lambda t: t[1])`?

Comment: @quamrana  I guess it depends on the order that the tuple should be in.

Comment: The OP seemed quite clear that a plain `min(s)` should provide `'0'`, but they were after code which produces `("0",1)`

Comment: last option should be ```min(((len(x), x) for x in my_set), key=lambda t: t[0])``` as written like that requires generator expression to be parenthesized